# Why does continuity on $\mathbb{T}$ imply that $f(-\pi) = f(\pi)$?

Tags: fourier-series

In Vretblad's *Fourier Analysis and its Applications*, it says:

> Suppose that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{T})$ , which means that both $f$ and its derivative $f'$ are continuous >on $\mathbb{T}$. We compute the Fourier coefficients of the derivative:
>
> $$ \begin{aligned} c_n(f') &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'(t) \ e^{-int} \ dt \\
> &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \Big[ f(t) e^{-int} \Big]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) (-in) e^{-int} dt  \\
> &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \Big( f(\pi)(−1)^n − f(−\pi)(−1)^n \Big) + in c_n(f) \\
> &= in c_n(f) \end{aligned}$$
> The fact that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{T}$ implies that $f(−\pi) = f(\pi)$.

So my questions is: how do we know that $f$ being continuous on $\mathbb{T}$ implies that $f(−\pi) = f(\pi)$?

Comment: @Falcon Sorry, $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book identifies a function that is $2\pi$-periodic as a function on the circle $\mathbf{T}$ (see Section 4.1 of the book):

> [image]

So when $f$ is a function on the circle, it must be true that
$$
f(-\pi)=f(-\pi+2\pi)=f(\pi).
$$

"Continuity" is actually not quite relevant here, although the author mentioned it.